# How to load libraries which export Typescript in next.js

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, webpack-4

When trying to import a component from a private library which exports *Typescript*, we get the following error message:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (82:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| // Types
> export type {
```

How could I fix that? I tried to explicitly include the libraries node modules in the *tsconfig* file:

```
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "node_modules/@private-lib/*.*"
  ],
  "exclude": [""]
```

but unfortunately, to no avail. There seems to be the possibility to change the *webpack* configuration of *next.js*, but trying to just shove in a Typescript loader did not work, unfortunately:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
      use: [
        options.defaultLoaders.babel,
        {
          loader: "ts-loader",
          options: {
            transpileOnly: true,
            experimentalWatchApi: true,
            onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

It produces this error:

```
./node_modules/process/browser.js
TypeError: /home/blub/bla/website/node_modules/process/browser.js: Property left of AssignmentExpression expected node to be of a type ["LVal"] but instead got "BooleanLiteral"
```

So is anybody out there who also faced this problem and could point me into the right direction? There seems to be a lot of magic at work here and I am kind of lost.

Answer (score 23):

I landed on this SO question after encountering what looks like the same issue: next.js project with typescript (`yarn create next-app --typescript`).

- yarn: 1.22.17
- next: 12.0.7
- node: 14.18.1

For me, this happened right after including a `ts` package (external to the next.js project) from within a `tsx` file (internal to the project). There appears to be transpiling magic behind the scenes, and is attempting to parse the ts file as some version of plain js.

My problem was solved by [next-transpile-modules](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules) (^9.0.0). Specifically, assuming you:

1. have `next.config.js` starting like this

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {
  },
}
```

2. have external TS library `private-lib` where `import { ... } from '/path/to/private-lib'` from a tsx file somewhere leads to the compile-time error.

FIX:

1. `yarn add next-transpile-modules`
2. `yarn add file:/path/to/private-lib`
3. change the import statements in the ts/tsx files for `private-lib`
4. update `next.config.js` to look something like this

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
// see https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules#readme
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['private-lib']);

module.exports = withTM({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {
  },
})
```

YMMV, HTH, #FixMagicWithMoreMagic

Comment: Excellent solution, webpack is always confusing to work with. This solved the issue like #FixMagicWithMoreMagic :) Cheers

Comment: This answer made my day. It works MAGICALLY!!

Comment: this answer has provided a very easy and working solution to the issue. please mark it accepted.

Comment: If using Nextjs 13 this answer does work, but you the answer below from Jaxon Crosmas is simpler and works too.

Answer (score 23):

This question is kind of old, so I thought I'd post an update to extend on *directed-laugh*'s original answer for anyone who stumbles across this issue.

As mentioned, transpiling the modules via `next.config.js` seems to be the solution. Though with NextJS 13.1 there is no need to install the additional `next-transpile-modules` package as these features are available natively in NextJS 13.1.

In `next.config.js`, just add the `transpilePackages` option and include the name of the `ts` package.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  transpilePackages: ['my-ts-package'],
}
```

See [Module Transpilation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#module-transpilation)

Comment: This just saved me after hours of trial and error with Nextjs 13.4.8 - many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing the issue is from transpiling `jsx?` files with `ts-loader` so it's safe to just only transpile `tsx?` file in case of `ts-loadder`:

```js
webpack: (config, options) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts)x?$/, // Just `tsx?` file only
    use: [
      // options.defaultLoaders.babel, I don't think it's necessary to have this loader too
      {
        loader: "ts-loader",
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
          experimentalWatchApi: true,
          onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  return config;
},
```

One more thing, If your repo is now using `jsx?` files which means importing `tsx?` file in a `jsx?` file, you might have to enable `{ "allowJs": true }` in `tsconfig.json`