# Why does my typescript node module when installed into my Next.js app trigger a "may need an appropriate loader" error?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, next.js

I wrote a TypeScript node module and installed into my Next.js app. However, when I try to run my Next.js app, the module triggers an error. Any ideas why this may be the case? Please see details below.

My typescript node module

```
import axios from 'axios'

//  AwsS3FileUploader()
//  A JavaScript library for file upload to AWS S3 bucket from the client side.

export const AwsS3FileUploader = class {
    url: string // unsigned or signed upload url
    headers: object // headers to be included in request
    data: Blob // file object to be included in request and uploaded to the S3 bucket

    constructor(initUrl: string, initHeaders: object, initData: Blob) {
        this.url = initUrl
        this.headers = initHeaders
        this.data = initData
    }

    async uploadFile(): Promise<object> {
        const res = await axios({
            url: this.url,
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: this.headers,
            data: this.data
        })
        if (res.status !== 200) return Promise.reject(res)
        return Promise.resolve({
            data: res.data,
            status: res.status,
            statusText: res.statusText
        })
    }
}
```

Error output

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:7)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the webpack configuration in my `next.config.js` file, as follows:

```
webpack(config, options) {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ts)x?$/, // Just `tsx?` file only
        use: [
            {
                loader: "ts-loader",
            },
        ],
    });
    return config;
}
```

Reference: [How to load libraries which export Typescript in next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64989575/how-to-load-libraries-which-export-typescript-in-next-js)