# How to fix "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I use next.js. When exporting a type in a file index.ts in a third party package an error occurs.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (23:7)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    > export type { Validate } from './src/nullable'
```

Comment: Check out the docs for typescript and Next.js - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in package.json, assuming the following dependency is added

"@yourproject/your-project": "file:../your-project",

then in next.config,  add transpilePackages: ['@yourproject/your-project'],.  This allows the loader to work directly on .ts files.

```
transpilePackages: ['@yourproject/your-project'],
webpack: (config) => {
       config.resolve.extensionAlias = {
      ".js": [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
      ".mjs": [".mts", ".mjs"],
      ".cjs": [".cts", ".cjs"],
    };
    return config;
  },
```

Comment: How can we do this in angular project?

Answer (score 5):

This issue occurs when you have fewer configurations than what you want to use.

In your case, you are trying to use Typescript on your NextJS project. Unfortunately, your Webpack configuration doesn't have a Typescript file loader.

There are two ways to solve this issue:

- Use NextJS Typescript project start example from [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-typescript)
- Add TS file loader on your Webpack configuration (reference in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64990954/6130753))