# Next.JS AppProps - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

I'm working on a Next.JS 13.5.6 app and am running into an error whenever I connect to the site in development mode. Production mode works if I build and start.

The error I get when I connect to the site is:

```
⨯ D:\Coding Projects\Gearbox\pages\_app.tsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   Component,
|   pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
> }: AppProps<{ session: Session }>) {
|   return (
|     <SessionProvider session={session}>
```

That error appears twice and is followed by:

```
⨯ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\name\Coding Projects\Gearbox\.next\fallback-build-manifest.json'
    at readFileSync (node:fs:453:20)
    at loadManifest (D:\Coding Projects\Gearbox\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-manifest.js:30:54)
    at loadManifestWithRetries (D:\Coding Projects\Gearbox\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:34:51)
    at async loadDefaultErrorComponentsImpl (D:\Coding Projects\Gearbox\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-default-error-components.js:30:24)
    at async DevServer.getFallbackErrorComponents (D:\Coding Projects\Gearbox\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:551:16)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (D:\Coding Projects\Gearbox\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1875:40)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (D:\Coding Projects\Gearbox\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:826:25)
    at async DevServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (D:\Coding Projects\Gearbox\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:572:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (D:\Coding Projects\Gearbox\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:728:17) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\name\\Coding Projects\\Gearbox\\.next\\fallback-build-manifest.json'
}
```

My _app.tsx is as follows:

```js
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { Session } from "next-auth";
import { DndProvider } from "react-dnd";
import { Analytics } from "@vercel/analytics/react";
import { SpeedInsights } from "@vercel/speed-insights/next";
import { HTML5Backend } from "react-dnd-html5-backend";

import { NextSeo } from "next-seo";

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}: AppProps<{ session: Session }>) {
  return ( /* JSX */ );
}
```

When I connect to the site, it displays `Internal Server Error`.

So far, I've tried recloning the repository, deleting `node_modules` and `.next`, and then running `npm ci`. Again, the app works in production mode.

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "pages/createTeam.tsx",
    "pages/[teamSlug]/createSeason.ksx",
    "pages/index.tsx",
    "pages/profile.jsx",
    "pages/[teamSlug]/index.jsx",
    "pages/[teamSlug]/[seasonSlug]/index.jsx",
    "pages/[teamSlug]/[seasonSlug]/[competitonSlug]/index.jsx",
    "lib/client/getSession.js",
    "index.js",
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

My next.config.js is:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  swcMinify: false,
  images: {
    domains: [
      "lh3.googleusercontent.com",
      "www.mouser.de",
      "www.firstinspires.org",
      "files.slack.com",
    ],
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Can you share your `tsconfig.json` and `next.config.js` file?

Comment: Done, both files are in the answer now.

Comment: Looks alright. It is hard to say. The only thing I could derive from the error and the configuration that Next.js is not recognizing the TypeScript syntax which is strange because Next has TS support out of the box and you are not overriding the Webpack loader configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space in my file path was the issue. I renamed my "Coding Projects" folder to "CodingProjects" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72621835/how-to-fix-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-current)

[transpilePackages](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/transpilePackages)

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: false,
    swcMinify: false,
    images: {
        domains: [
            "lh3.googleusercontent.com",
            "www.mouser.de",
            "www.firstinspires.org",
            "files.slack.com",
        ],
    },
    transpilePackages: [
        'react-dnd-html5-backend',
        'react-dnd',
    ],
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const DndProvider = dynamic(
  () => import("react-dnd").then((dnd) => dnd.DndProvider),
  { ssr: false }
);
const HTML5Backend: any = dynamic(
  () =>
    import('react-dnd-html5-backend').then((html) => html.HTML5Backend as any),
  { ssr: false }
);
```

Comment: Results in `⨯ Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './D:/Coding Projects/Gearbox/node_modules/next/dist/client/next-dev.js' in 'C:\Users\name\Coding Projects\Gearbox'`

Comment: Can you share your minimal project on Github? I'll run it locally to check the problem. I see you have solved this problem. Awesome.