# Using a ts-loader custom transformer with NextJS

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, build, swc-compiler

I've fallen in love with the [ts-runtime-checks](https://github.com/GoogleFeud/ts-runtime-checks) library and want to incorporate it into my NextJS project: issue is that it's a code transformer (changes how code compiles) and needs to be run before the main typescript compilation. **Is there a way to hook this plugin into the NextJS compilation cleanly?**

This library has a good, easy setup if one is using `ts-loader` for compilation. This is, from their documentation, as follows:

```js
const TsRuntimeChecks = require("ts-runtime-checks").default;

options: {
      getCustomTransformers: program => {
        before: [TsRuntimeChecks(program)]
      }
}
```

I've seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64989575/how-to-load-libraries-which-export-typescript-in-next-js) that there is a way to call `ts-loader` by altering the webpack in the project `next.config` however, it seems like this is just for compilation of additional files, and I can't get this working as a pre-compilation step.

I've also read in [Next documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/nextjs-compiler#swc-plugins-experimental) that the compilation actually uses the [SWC compiler](https://swc.rs/docs/getting-started) and exposes some experimental options for adding custom plugins here. And, although it seems like these plugins have to probably be WASM-based, it also claims one can just enter the node package name as a plugin. However, the following `next.config` does not work (with `failed to invoke <ts-runtime-checks path> as js transform plugin`):

```js
const TsRuntimeChecks = require("ts-runtime-checks").default;

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  // add ts runtime checks to pre-compilation
  experimental: {
    swcPlugins: [[ 'ts-runtime-checks', {} ]], 
  },
}
```

Is there any way to get Next to run this transformer natively? Should I try to build a SWC WASM wrapper for the library? Would appreciate insight from either direction...